# Как вывести и как положить данные из базы данных с помощью AJA?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

Делаю элементарный Todo с AJAX что бы набить руку, однако столкнулся с нехваткой знаний. Как при добавлении одной записи запускать  putTodoInBase($db), и одновременно выводить записи с помощью getAllTodo($db). В ответе пожалуйста используйте нативный JS.

Имеется бд с такими полями:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Имеется ванильный JS:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    let todoButton = document.querySelector("#todo .action span");
    todoButton.onclick = addTodo;
    /**/
}
function createLi(todoText){
     let todoWrapp = document.querySelector(".itemsWrap #todoList");
     let li = document.createElement('li');
     li.className = "oneTodo";
     li.innerHTML = todoText;
     todoWrapp.prepend(li);
     let span = document.createElement('span');
     span.className = "deleteButton";
     span.innerHTML = "X";
     li.prepend(span);
     li.onclick = addLine;
     span.onclick = removeTodo;
     return li;
}
function addTodo(text) {
    let data = new Date();
    let dateNow =  data.getFullYear() + '/' + addZero(data.getMonth()) + '/' + addZero(data.getHours()) + ':' + addZero(data.getMinutes());
    let textAreaValue = document.querySelector("textarea[name = value]").value;
    let todoListWrapp = document.querySelector(".itemsWrap #todoList");
    let createdLi = createLi(textAreaValue);
    let params = 'todo-description='+textAreaValue+'&'+'date='+ dateNow;
    ajaxPost(params); 
}

function removeTodo() {
    let parent = this.parentNode;
    parent.remove();
}

function ajaxPost(params) {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            let responsText = request.responseText;
            elem.innerHTML = responsText;
        };
    };
    request.open('POST', 'ajax.php');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlEncoded');
    request.send(params);

}
```

HTML

```
    <div id="root">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="todo">
                <div  id="todoWrapp" class="todoWrap">
                    <h1 class="todoName">ToDo Ajax</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="action">
                    <form id="form">
                        <textarea name="value" id="writeTodo" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                        <span>Р”РµР»Рѕ!</span>
                    </form>
                </div>
               <div class="itemsWrap">
                    <ul class="todoList" id="todoList">
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

И файлик php

```
    $value = $_POST['todo-description'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];

    /* foreach ($_POST as $post_var){
      echo strtoupper( $post_var);
      } */
    function putTodoInBase($db) {
        $k = rand(1,1000);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `Todo` (`id`, `todo-name`, `todo-description`, `date`) VALUES ('NULL', '$k', '$value','$date')";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    function getAllTodo($db) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Todo`";
    $result = array();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $res = $stmt->execute();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[$row['id']] = $row;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: `...и одновременно выводить записи с помощью getAllTodo($db)` -> что это значит, не совсем понятно.

Comment: @ВладВолков  как мне добавить дело  AJAX запросом и как это дело  AJAX запросом вывести.